# What syntax is used to SELECT a constant field value from a JavaDB database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, derby

I'm using `UNION ALL` to combine the results of several `SELECT` queries into one `ResultSet`. I use constant field values to identify which statement produced each row. This works well with MySQL, but Java DB is throwing `SQLSyntaxErrorException`, pointing at the comma after the first constant field value.

**What syntax is used to select constant field values in** `SELECT` **queries against JavaDB databases?**

The first `SELECT` has ~100 columns with varying data types, and the following `SELECT`s are padded to match the correct number of columns. I've it [here](http://pastebin.com/RZck3DwW). The statements currently look like this:

```
select
    (0, ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST)
from person 
where ID=500
union all
select 
    (1, COMMTYPE_ID, NULL, NULL)
from person_commtype 
where PERSON_ID=500
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 2, column 7.
```

I have also tried casting the value, and removing the parentheses, like so:

```
select
    (cast(0 as integer), ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST)
from person 
where ID=500

select
    0, ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST
from person
where ID=500
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/tuning/ctuntransform14044.html

Answer (score 4):

Remove the brackets from around your list of fields in the `SELECT` clause.

```
select
    0, ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST
from person 
where ID=500
union all
select 
    1, COMMTYPE_ID, NULL, NULL
from person_commtype 
where PERSON_ID=500
```

Comment: I used that form initially. It works well against MySQL, but it throws `SQLSyntaxErrorException` for the `NULL` after `COMMTYPE_ID` when run against Java DB. The [Mimer SQL validator](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser99/index.tml) suggested adding the parentheses, which solved that problem.

Comment: Not overly familiar with Java DB, but have you tried casting the NULL to the correct data type in the second half of your union?

Comment: @Keeblebrox: there must be something you are not telling use because the syntax is certainly valid in Derby (and thus in should work in JavaDB).

Comment: @DavidM: I haven't tried casting the `NULL` values to an appropriate type yet. It will take some fairly significant modifications, but I'll try it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The queries have significantly more columns being selected, so I truncated most of them for brevity. So far they haven't seemed to influence the problem, but I'll update the question in case it's relevant.

Comment: @Keeblebrox: fair enough. But it must be something different then as the basic syntax **is** correct. You probably should put your statement e.g. to pastebin or something similar.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I've added a paste of the full query. Hopefully David M's comment will turn out to be correct, because I'm pretty sure you're right about the syntax being valid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Apache Derby doesn't support

```
select null from test
```

Instead you have to cast the null to the right type:

```
select cast(null as varchar(255)) from test
```

So the query would look like:

```
select
    0, ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST
from person where ID=500
union all
select 
    1, COMMTYPE_ID, 
    cast(NULL as varchar(255)), 
    cast(NULL as varchar(255))
from person_commtype where PERSON_ID=500
```

You also have to remove the brackets around your column list, because that's not standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your numbers in single quotes.

```
select
    ('0', ID, NAME_FIRST, NAME_LAST)
from person 
where ID=500
union all
select 
    ('1', COMMTYPE_ID, NULL, NULL)
from person_commtype 
where PERSON_ID=500
```

Comment: Numbers should **never** be put in single quotes, because then they aren't numbers any longer