# UNION two tables with different number of columns

Tags: sql, derby

I am trying to perform a `UNION` between two tables that have a different number of columns. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns)  I know that you need to add extra null columns on the table with fewer columns but doing this causes the following error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "null" at line 1, column 75.
```

The query is:

```
SELECT column1, column2 
from APP.lefttable 
WHERE column2 = 'value' 
union all 
select column1, null as column2 
from APP.righttable";
```

I only want a single column on the right hand side of the `UNION` clause so I am trying to make one of the columns null but the above error appears.

If it helps I'm doing this in a Java application using Apache Derby as my RDBMS.

Comment: The query seems ok. Can you remove the `as column2` from the second part of the union?

Comment: I tried that earlier as well, just tried it again and got the same error.

Comment: Can you post the exact query you have - without altering table or column names? I suspect there is some reserved keyword used. Or you missed the comma before `NULL`

Comment: The UNION isn't the problem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533409/330315

Comment: I think ybercube has it. I went on the link s/he put up and it says you have to do some casting which doesn't bring up the error anymore. Happy days! Apologies for the duplicate post.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name found the link - and the issue.

Comment: Ah well then, thanks to both I suppose! No way of marking it as the answer even though it's just a comment? (And it just links to another question)

Comment: There's probably no need in a formal answer as this question is likely to be soon closed as a duplicate. (It's fine, you don't need to worry about that.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT * from
    (
    SELECT column1, column2 from APP.lefttable WHERE column2 = 'value' 
    union all 
    SELECT column1,NULL AS Column2 from APP.righttable
    )
```

Comment: It needs an alias for the derived table - not sure about Derby but surely in most DBMS.

Comment: Same error as before unfortunately. Seems like Derby is pretty painful for this sort of thing. Your example works in MySQL (just tried it on a different DB) so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if column2 of your derived table is being defined as NOT NULL based on the first query in the union.  What if you switch your queries:

```
select column1, null as column2 from APP.righttable"
union all 
SELECT column1, column2 from APP.lefttable WHERE column2 = 'value';
```